# Using two GitHub account in same device: `fatal: Could not read from remote repository`

Tags: git, github, remote-access, fatal-error

[This is the config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJUCQ.png)

Whenever I tried to push

```
$ git push origin master
```

The error is:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-kumaramit114920: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: for config file please tab on " the config file is as follow"

Comment: What does `ssh -T git@github-kumaramit114920` say?

Comment: Please add the config file's content in plain text here and read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for the reasons

Comment: @lucascavalcante please be careful to ensure that the triple backticks (```) are on their own line.  Your edit hid a line of the error message, which I've now corrected.

Comment: Heres the config file sorry for inconvincent way:- the config is as follows:

#Default GitHub
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa


Host github-kumaramit114920
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_kumaramit114920

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname github-kumaramit114920: Name or service not known